# How to protect wp-login from attack on apache/nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I would like to ask you if you know any method in apache or nginx to restrict the access to wp-login, but not for the whole server. What I mean is:

For example there is a server with Apache/Nginx and there are a lot of hits to wp-login.php /xmrlpc.php or admin-ajax.php . The load of the server is getting really high if I do not deny the access via .htaccess file for the whole server. Is there any configuration or software (not wp plugins) which might help in my case? For example if its possible to restrict the access if the same IP is hitting wp-login.php more than X(number) times?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Should be asked on ServerFault, but you can achieve this using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban or a similar tool

Comment: Hi, im not too sure I understand your question, why dont you disallow it from your directory? PS, I didnt give you the down vote, i'm not to sure why someone would, perhaps its how you phrased it.

Answer (score 3):

## It sounds like you're looking for [Nginx rate limiting](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html).

Below is an excerpt from my blog about how to configure rate limiting in Nginx specifically for wp-login.php.

### [Using Rate Limiting in Nginx](https://blog.arnonerba.com/2016/07/server-logs-explained-part-3)

Nginx has some great documentation on how to implement rate limiting, but I am going to provide an example of how to optimize it for WordPress. Setting up rate limiting in Nginx is simple, and only requires two components:

1. We must define a zone in the main `nginx.conf` file.
2. We must implement that zone in the WordPress login location block. To define the zone, we use `limit_req_zone` and, optionally, `limit_req_status`. These directives go inside the `http` block of the main `nginx.conf` configuration file.

The code:

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=wordpress:10m rate=15r/m;
    limit_req_status 429;
}
```

The above snippet defines a 10 MB zone named “wordpress” that allows a maximum of 15 requests per minute from any one IP address. The `limit_req_zone` requires a variable, or key. In this case, the key is `$binary_remote_addr`, or the IP address of the client. Nginx will use a maximum of 10 MB of memory to store the keys, and if a key exceeds the maximum number of allowed requests, Nginx will terminate the connection and return the status code defined in `limit_req_status`. The default code is `503 Service Unavailable`, but I prefer the more specific `429 Too Many Requests` response. Keep in mind that Nginx will display a blank page to the client for non-standard HTTP codes if you have not set a custom error page using the `error_page` directive.

You can name the zone anything you want (it is named “wordpress” in the example above) and you can also define any rate limit you feel is appropriate. I found that allowing a maximum of 15 requests per minute is restrictive enough to severely hamper a brute-force attack but is permissive enough not to interfere with end-users who legitimately mistyped their passwords.

To actually use the zone, we must implement it by adding this code to the WordPress login location block:

```
location = /wp-login.php {
    limit_req zone=wordpress;
    # add your PHP fastcgi config here
}
```

This tells Nginx to limit requests to the `/wp-login.php` page using the parameters specified in the zone we defined above. Make sure you replace “wordpress” with whatever you named your zone in the previous step. Restart or reload Nginx and rapidly refresh your login page to test if the new brute-force protection is working. If you refresh faster than the rate you defined in `limit_req_zone`, the server will return the status code defined in `limit_req_status`.

*Obligatory note: if you’ve read other guides on how to set up rate limiting with Nginx, you may have seen other syntaxes used, such as `limit_req zone=one burst=1 nodelay`. The `burst` and `nodelay` options are more complex and allow you to control what happens to excess requests. They are not necessary in this context, since we want any excess brute-force attempts to be immediately rejected, but I would highly encourage you to read the documentation for them here.*

Source: https://blog.arnonerba.com/2016/07/server-logs-explained-part-3

Comment: Mods: This answer is directly copy/pasted but is my own content that directly answers this question. I included the relevant section but left the link since there is more info in the full article. Is there a better way or is this an appropriate answer?

Comment: @Armon I am trying your solution, however there are some strange behaviors. I wrote about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662918/how-to-protect-wp-login-from-attack-on-apache-nginx

Can you please take a look?

Comment: @Pikk it looks like that's the link to this question. Did you post another comment?